# How to read xml with select query?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i have this XML file.

```
<tokens>
    <token id="1" >
      <id>1</id>
      <nome>"Mare"</nome>
      <numeroSillabe>"2"</numeroSillabe>
      <sillabaIniziale>"ma"</sillabaIniziale>
      <immagine>"mare.jpg"</immagine>
      <rima>"are"</rima>
    </token>
<tokens>
```

So i would like to select all token have rima=are.
This is my code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("Content\\Token.xml");
String query = "//token";
            if (isRima)
            {
                query += "[rima='are']";
            }
 List<XmlNode> mappa = document.SelectNodes(query).OfType<XmlNode>().ToList();
```

But the mappa is empty. What is wrong?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Thus content of `rima` element is `"are"` (with double quotes) you should add these quotes to content you are checking (and escape them):

```
query += "[rima='\"are\"']";
```

Side note - consider to use Linq to Xml for parsing Xml. You can compose query depending on conditions:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Content\\Token.xml");
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("token");
if (isRima)
    query = query.Where(t => (string)t.Element("rima") == "\"are\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to query your xml:

```
var result = document.Element("tokens")
                   .Elements("token")
                   .Where(x => (string)x.Element("rima") == "\"are\"");
```

don't forget `System.Linq`."

Comment: 1) that does not answers what is wrong 2) rima is not attribute 3) its content is not `are`

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList res = doc.SelectNodes("//tokens//token//rima[.='" + "\"are\"" + "']");
```

by this you will get all the rima node which has value "are".

Then if you need token node, loop through with res like this.

```
        foreach (XmlNode item in res)
        {
            XmlNode tokenNode = item.ParentNode;
        }
```